# Conditional replace in XML files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm replacing a text in XML files recursively using PowerShell. The script is working fine in replacing. However the XML files also have file paths which should not be replaced. This is the script currently being used

```bsh
if ( $content -match ' web site | web-site ' ) {
    $content -replace ' web site ',' New Site ' -replace ' web-site ',' New Site ' |
        Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
```

For example if the XML file has

```xml
<title>web site</title>
<subtitle>web-site</subtitle>
<path>c:/web site/website.xml</path>
```

the expected output is should look like below. The matching text in file paths should be ignored. How can I add a condition to ignore the string if its between `/web site/` or `/web-site.xml`?

```xml
<title>New Site</title>
<subtitle>New Site</subtitle>
<path>c:/web site/website.xml</path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **quick fix**, but note that **a more robust solution would use PowerShell's XML parsing features**: see [Ansgar Wiecher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38535535/45375):

<sup>Note: This answer assumes that the strings of interest do not conflict with syntactical elements of the XML document, such as element names and attribute names (which happens to work for the *specific* strings in question), which illustrates why using a real XML parser is the better choice.</sup>

```
$content = @'
<doc>
<title>web site</title>
<subtitle>web-site</subtitle>
<path>c:/web site/website.xml</path>
</doc>
'@

$modifiedContent = $content -replace ''([^/])web[ -]site([^/])', '$1New Site$2'
# Replace 'web site' and 'web-site' if not preceded or followed by a '/'.
# Note: `web[ -]site` is the equivalent of `web site|web-site`

if ($modifiedContent -cne $content) { # If contents have changed, save.
  Out-File -InputObject $modifiedContent $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
}
```

Comment: @Ansgar and mklement there are occurrences where it will have spaces before and after the text too like '<description> new web site</description>' thats why I wanted to know if there's any quick fix for ignoring /text/ with any regex. IS there any quickfix fox for this or can you give me a lead to handle this in XML parsing

Comment: @user2628187: Please see my update. Ansgar's answer specifically targets the `title` and `subtitle` elements only, so I would expect it to work as-is (unless you don't want to use an explicit list of element names).

Answer (score 4):

It's usually far more efficient and far less error-prone to handle XML as XML. Select the nodes you want to update, then save the modified data back to a file.

```bsh
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[self::title or self::subtitle]') |
    Where-Object { $_.'#text' -match 'web.site' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = 'New Site' }
$xml.Save($filename)
```

If you need to modify a substring of the node text you could do something like this:

```bsh
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[self::title or self::subtitle]') |
    Where-Object { $_.'#text' -match 'web.site' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = $_.'#text' -replace 'web.site', 'New Site' }
$xml.Save($filename)
```

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest using `-match 'web[ -]site'` to more closely match the OP's code; is there a particular reason you're using `self::`? Seems to work fine without it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it works without the `self` axis as well.

Comment: yes but the problen is the file path can come in many different xml tags so this option cannot be used. Do you know if we can specify the previous and last text in form of regex to be ignored  like the slach before and after  /web site/

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide representative samples for input and desired output instead of "something like this or other, and I want the solution to be thisandthat".

Comment: @user2628187 and Ansgar  How can I use this for multiple matches with OR condition
'$content -replace '(^|[^/])web-site([^/]|$)|(^|[^/])web-site([^.]|$)', '$1new-Site$2' |'
        Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
Basically I'm trying to ignore strings like  /web-site/ and /web-site.

Comment: Do **NOT** use string replacements on unparsed XML. ***EVER.*** Identify the nodes where you want to change the (sub)string, then adjust the XPath expression accordingly (`//*[nodeA or nodeB or nodeC or ...]`).